# Explanation on Zemo's plan

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war

I just watched *Captain America: Civil War* and these were the questions I had after leaving the theatre:

1. Was Zemo's plan really that brilliant? Okay so I understood that he wanted to pit the Avengers against each other. But all of that was riding on the footage of Bucky killing Stark's parents. Was there any part in the movie that suggested that the footage would be found in Siberia? If not, his elaborate plan would have actually gone to waste.
2. This one doesn't really bother me, but I still got to know. After Zemo used the code words to reset his brain, how did Bucky come back to his senses? Is it water? Because I think it's water.

Comment: You might want to separate those two questions into individual questions to make them each assessable, answerable and acceptable on their own merits, since they are complete unrelated to one another. (Or concentrate on the scond question, since the first one seems quite opinion-based.)

Comment: Both question are completely unrelated, kindly ask them separately .

Answer (score 3):

**1. Was Zemo's plan really that brilliant?**

From my [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/127568/1148) to a similar question on Scifi.SE:

> I think his primary objective throughout the movie was to obtain hard evidence that the Winter Soldier has killed Stark's parents, in order to turn Stark against the Winter Soldier and presumably Captain America. I don't think he necessarily *originally planned* to have them meet him in Siberia.
>
> However, as events played out, he eventually decided that dropping the false trail of the inactive Winter Soldiers would likely lead the Avengers there.

The assumption here is that Zemo was able to figure out (or at least had a strong guess) that the accident that killed Stark's parents was really an assassination performed by *The* Winter Soldier from the Hydra documents leaked by Black Widow. Had he obtained the information he needed from that Russian guy in his house, he wouldn't have had to murder the shrink to get close to Bucky in order to mind control him. (He probably would have still framed him for the bombing of the U.N. though, to draw him out).

**2. How did Bucky come back to his senses?**

We don't know what his orders were. They could have been as simple as "escape from this UN facility." After he was knocked unconscious from the helicopter crash and woke up, maybe his saw that his mission was a success.

Zemo needs Bucky to team up with Captain America to create the conflict with Tony Stark, so maybe he was instructed to revert back to himself after getting away.

Or maybe it was the water.

Comment: did black widow hit him with a frying pan? worked for clint...

Comment: Captain America hit him with a falling helicopter. Same difference.